# Does SvelteKit relies on NodeJS?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

SvelteKit provides a "skeleton" for multi-page app, of which two features are particularly interesting for me: 1) a routing system (src/routes); 2) server-side rendering.

My question is: does SvelteKit rely on NodeJS?  I use Go as backend server, which works well with VueJS frontend. I just simply copy the output of webpack (the dist folder) to my go source tree and compile it into a single executable.

Does that work with SvelteKit?

**EDIT**

Background: I am primarily a Go programmer. Before I know Svelte, I purely uses Bootstrap + vanilla JS for frontend development.  I've tried VueJS, but give up.  The purpose of this question is to ask: **is it worth to learn SvelteKit or just Svelte?**

In another word, SSR is "nice to have" for me. However if the "routing" architecture does not work without Node, then I feel I'd better just go with Svelte, or, is there any other reason to choose SvelteKit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean static rendering from

> I just simply copy the output of webpack

If you want to do static rendering with SvelteKit, install `@sveltejs/adapter-static@next` and plug it into your `svelte.config.js` as `import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';`.

You may have to set an extra property, `prerender`, in the config, that way Svelte knows to do prerendering for any logic in the page, so it can build correctly.

An example `svelte.config.js` file that does this:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        prerender: {
            default: true
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

That way, when you do `npm run build` in the directory containing the project, it will output to the `build` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The server-side routing and rendering features of SvelteKit are tied to its implementation, which is in Node.

In particular, server-side rendering of Svelte components will unavoidably depend on Node at some level, because the Svelte compiler is written in TypeScript.

---

SvelteKit is intended to be an all-in-one solution for web applications, but you can configure it instead to output a pre-rendered static site (see LeoDog896's answer), with client-side routing intact.

It should be trivial to set up a Go server to serve the static site so that routing works as expected. The only missing piece would be SSR, which is strongly tied to SvelteKit's own server implementation.

Comment: Technically, JS/TS does not directly imply Node, the latter could for example also run in Deno. But often there are dependencies on various NPM packages which are only compatible with Node.

Comment: True, I could have highlighted this distinction, though I took the question to be whether or not some kind of ECMAScript runtime is required.